# Не отправляется картинка Telgegram бот

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Столкнулся с проблемой что ссылка на картинку не имеет расширения, и при попытке отправить сообщение

```
bot.send_photo(chat_id, "https://surgebook.com/uploads/user_160759/covers/1gyxx0joec_thumb_340")
```

вылетает ошибка

> telebot.apihelper.ApiException: A request to the Telegram API was
> unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:
> [b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: wrong file
> identifier/HTTP URL specified"}'] " 2020-07-31 13:55:10,814

> (**init**.py:455 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the
> Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad
> Request. Response body:
> [b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: wrong file
> identifier/HTTP URL specified"}']"

если брать любою другое изображение в котором url заканчивается .jpg .png, отправка проходит успешно . Есть какие-то методы что-бы решить проблему без скачивания файла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае если по ссылке действительно находится файл изображения а не страница содержащая изображение и еще что-то:

```py
response = requests.get("https://surgebook.com/uploads/user_160759/covers/1gyxx0joec_thumb_340")
bot.send_photo(chat_id, response.content)
```